# Fix Broken PrimeFaces 8.0.0 message bubble

Tags: jquery, primefaces

PrimeFaces comes with it's bundled jquery version from maven.
Recently we had to update that jquery version to latest due to some security issues.
PrimeFace 8.0.0 uses jQuery version 3.4.1 and we are overriding the PrimeFaces' request to use jQuery 3.5.1 instead.

The web application functionality were retained but we encountered UI issues specially in the message bubble.

The picture below were the changes that occurred before and after the jQuery update

[Before jQuery Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtJgl.png)

[After jQuery Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcvjv.png)

Any Idea to fix the broken message bubble? Overriding the PrimeFaces css maybe? Thanks-

Comment: Try with PrimeFaces 10. If that does not help, include a [mcve], as this question does not contain enough info to answer it. For example, what is a "message bubble"?

Answer (score 1):

You can't upgrade jQuery like that it breaks things.

See ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5807

You need to upgrade to Elite 8.0.2 or higher it has 3.5.0 built in but it required significant changes to PF code.  So you can't just drop your own version in.