# Jquery 3.4.1 -> 3.5.0 Visual Distortion

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I have a java spring application that is using Primefaces 6.2. Primefaces 6.2 comes with Jquery 3.2.1.

I want to have minumum Jquery 3.5.0 without upgrading Primefaces. I managed to do it with custom handler that changes jquery version to which I give.

Although there were no problems in 3.2.1, 3.3.1 and 3.4.1 versions, when I switched to 3.5.0, some information messages and objects in textboxes have visual disturbances. Despite these disturbances, functions and pages work properly.

How an information message looks like in 3.4.1:

[image: 3.4.1]

Distorted in 3.5.0:

[image: Distorted in 3.5.0]

How can I solve this problem by keeping Primefaces 6.2 and Jquery 3.5.0?

Comment: Please, clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly the problem.
As currently written, it's hard to say exactly what happened beyond a version change or migration.
The problem you mention may simply be due to a style problem and not a version change.

Comment: @Borja As in the screenshots I attached, while there was no glitch in Jquery 3.4.1, a visual glitch appeared only after I changed the jquery version to 3.5.0.

Answer (score 4):

As explained [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5807), changes security fix that were implemented in JQuery 3.5.0 broke some components in Primefaces, so it should accompany that change to the JQuery 3.5.0 version by changing primefaces to 8.0.2.

You can get more information in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381008/fix-broken-primefaces-8-0-0-message-bubble), or in [this post from github](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5807)

It may help you to consult [this Primefaces migration guide](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/migrationguide) where the changes are explained depending on the version

Comment: Thank you, I guess I have no choice but to try to upgrade primefaces version.

Comment: @deryauzunyurt1 Yes, you need to upgrade, but version 8.0.2 is not available for free; only 8.0 is available. To use 8.0.2, you need a paid subscription.

Comment: Yes, I think so, it may help you to consult this Primefaces migration guide where the changes are explained depending on the version: (I also edited it in the answer)
https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/migrationguide

Answer (score 3):

Not enough characters in a comment, so I'll post this as an answer instead. Just don't try to cling on to an old version of PrimeFaces, instead upgrade your PrimeFaces version. You will benefit from **all** security updates (not only jQuery updates) and on top of that, all those updates have been tested. So it's less likely you will run into issues as apposed to trying to patch things yourself. Apart from the security updates you will also benefit from numerous bug fixes when you simply upgrade PrimeFaces. Just follow the [migration guides](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/14_0_0/#/../migrationguide/migrationguide) and it should be pretty straightforward.